# How to make a single window vnc session with x11vnc?

Tags: vnc

I want to create a VNC session to expose a single application that I start on a virtual display. And I want to do it with x11vnc because after that I can expose it through noVNC.

The problem is that x11vnc allows me to create a virtual display:

```
x11vnc -create
```

... or to expose a single window of an already launched application

```
x11vnc -id 0x200002
```

but I did not find any option to start a new application in a new virtual display (like xstartup for vncserver).

Answer (score 6):

So far the only solution I found is to do all the procedure manually

```
# create a virtual display on the compute node
Xvnc :33 &

# launch the application on this virtual display
export DISPLAY=:33
glxgears &

# find out its window id
xwininfo -root -children

# -> xwininfo: Window id: 0xdc (the root window) (has no name)
#
#  Root window id: 0xdc (the root window) (has no name)
#  Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
#     1 child:
#     0x200002 "glxgears": ()  300x300+0+0  +0+0

# start the vnc server with this specifix xid
x11vnc -id 0x200002 &
```

It works but it is a bit complex and I still have to write a small command to get the xid automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "reputation" to write a comment, so I have to write my own answer despite this being just a modification to Michael's answer, which TBH I have yet to test. I came up with a quick hack to get the window ID since I won't be able to input it manually. Try this to find out the Window ID:

```
window_id=$(xwininfo -root -tree | grep glxgears | tail -n1 | sed "s/^[ \t]*//" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

So you're getting the tree, filtering for the program you're looking for, getting the last option, removing trailing whitespace, then getting only the first column, and saving it. Then you can run...

```
x11vnc -id $window_id &
```

...to the same effect as Michael's answer. Hopefully. Like I said, it's a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one for sharing windows at the office !

```sh
echo "Select Window...";x11vnc -id $(xwininfo|grep -oP '(?<=id: ).*(?= ")') -viewonly -forever
```

Or a shorter one:

```sh
x11vnc -id pick -viewonly -forever
```

Comment: Good solution but it is interactive. I use the VNC servers in batch mode to run interactive/graphic applications from a server node (without actual display).

Comment: Yeah, my example is meant to be interactive :D

Comment: The following command reproduce the same feature: `x11vnc -id pick -viewonly -forever`

Answer (score 0):

x11vnc supports sharing a window based on it’s id. Here you can take simulator as window and share it.

Below is   steps:

- Run `xwininfo` from a terminal. Click on the window you want to
  share. `xwininfo` will print out the window id.
- Run `x11vnc -id win_id take win_id from above steps.

Example command:

```
 x11vnc -id 0x2800005
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the name of the window (better for scripting), you could remove a few steps and just use xwininfo to get the window by name, then filter out the window ID from the first line using grep:

```
x11vnc --forever -id $(xwininfo -name "window_title" | grep -Po "0x\d{7}" -m1)
```